# Python - automatically installing dependencies

Tags: python, selenium, dependency-management

I am hoping to use Python to write a script that will automate the change control ticket creation process at the organization I am consulting at. The users should be able to double click a file (or worst case, just run the script from the terminal) and have it do its thing. In other words, the only thing I want them to have to install is Python.

However, the script is likely to make use of a couple other resources, including Selenium. Is there a way that when the analysts run the script, it can check if Selenium and any other dependencies are installed and install them if not? Something like NPM does?

A bonus Selenium-related question if anybody wants to step forward -- how do you check if the user is logged in to a specific website given that the access token the users will have received is browser specific and Selenium will be operating a headless browser? And is there a secure way to prompt the users to log in if they are not already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login verification is still an open question, but it turns out you can require dependencies from a setup.py file if you distribute your script in a package:
[Require Dependencies](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html)